# hexdump: How to suppress offset column in hex mode

Tags: hexdump

I wanted to get 16 bytes from a binary file, starting from 5th byte, no separation of bytes or words by spaces.

`hexdump` will do what I want, just the offset column is disturbing the output:

```
$ hexdump -s5 -n16 -xe '/1 "%01X"' binfile
```

`od` does the task fine as well and can even be told to suppress the offset column, although I had to use `sed` to get rid of the spacing:

```
$ od -An -tx1 -j5 -N16 | sed 's/ //g' binfile
```

I am sure it will work without `sed`, but as I had many issues with `od` in hex mode related to endianness (swapped bytes), this is not as easy as it looks.
For instance, changing `-tx1` to anything higher will swap the bytes and mess up the 128-bit value that I want. `-tx1` is fine, but unlike `hexdump` I haven't found a way to get rid of the spaces *while* keeping byte order as-is at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

The `-x` option instructs hexdump to display offsets, and specifying a format afterwards doesn't suppress that. Get rid of the `-x` option.

```
$ hexdump -s5 -n16 -e '/1 "%01X"' <<<@abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz; echo
65666768696A6B6C6D6E6F7071727374
```

If you want to read two-byte values in the platform's endianness the way `-x` does (which swaps the two bytes on little-endian platforms such as x86 and ARM¹), use `%02X` instead of `%01X`.

¹  <sub>ARM CPUs support both endiannesses, but almost all Unix systems use them in little-endian mode.</sub>

Comment: Thanks! Though it almost feels embarrassing now, there is a good reason why I didn't get that first time. First of all, I come from `od` times (when the `hexdump`|`hd` tool didn't even exist) - and the `-x` option meant hex mode (since `od`'s default mode is __octal__). Second, the man page of `hexdump` reads "Two-byte hexadecimal mode" for its `-x` option. The offset thing is just hidden away in the following text, but I thought, hey, 2B hex mode, that's just what I'm in need of here. :)

Comment: Well, this gets even more interesting. Though you said that the `-x` option *triggers* the offset column, `hexdump` appears to use it per default in some cases. That is, __if the only argument to `hexdump`is the filename, offset column will be displayed too__! Yes, without specifying `-x`. (Just figured that out.)

Comment: @Gilles: How `%02X` swap endianness?

Comment: @cuonglm `%02X` prints two-byte values at a time. Each value is read in the platform's endianness and is printed with the most significant hexadecimal digit first. The most common platforms running Unix today (x86 as well as any ARM that you're likely to encounter) are little-endian, so in this two-byte value the first byte contains the least significant two hexadecimal digits. I should have mentioned that this depends on the platform's endianness.